# What are all the XTP_THREAD_POOL processes doing?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, memory-optimized-tables

I just ran `sp_who` on my SQL Server 2016 instance that uses `MEMORY_OPTIMIZED` tables, and I see several `XTP_THREAD_POOL` processes running:

[image: xtp nonsense]

Some other details about the output:

- There are exactly 6 `XTP_THREAD_POOL` rows in the resultset
- My system has two logical cores

  - Specifically, it's a VM with 2 sockets - each socket housing a 1-core processor
- All of these tasks are running as background (sa)

What are these processes doing?  I'm not finding much on Google about this task name.

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Information about these tasks is, indeed, hard to come by.

The docs ([Creating and Managing Storage for In-Memory OLTP -> Scalability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/scalability?view=sql-server-2017)) say that

> In SQL Server 2016 (13.x), there are multiple concurrent threads responsible to persist changes to memory-optimized tables.

And while the docs don't mention the "cmd" value that might be associated with these concurrent threads, there is [a PowerPoint from Bob Ward](https://www.sqlsaturday.com/SessionDownload.aspx?suid=13798) that links to the doc page above and adds more details about this process:

> You may see these as command = `XTP_THREAD_POOL` or `XTP_PREEPMTIVE_TASK`

**So these tasks are keeping the data and delta files used by in-memory OLTP up-to-date.**  They run in the background all the time.  While they are idle, they rack up [DISPATCHER_QUEUE_SEMAPHORE](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/dispatcher_queue_semaphore/) waits.

---

The presentation also mentions that:

> Pools should get no bigger than # logical CPUs...

So it's a little surprising to see 6 of these processes running on a 2-processor box.  This might be a bug, or things could have changed since Bob's PowerPoint presentation.  Hopefully someone with more Hekaton smarts than me will come by and weigh in.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SQL 2019 and notice these XTP_THREAD_POOL cmd threads show up when I use Studio Manager (SSMS) and use a user database.

```
select Hostname, program_name, db_name(dbid) AS 'Database', *
    FROM master..sysprocesses
        WHERE spid >50
```

Shows these new threads.  I'm not using in-memory indexes or anything unless 2019 has this enabled.

SQL 2019 CU 08 shows the cmd threads.

SQL 2019 CU 05 does not.